# How to convert bsoncxx::array::element to bsoncxx::document::element?

Tags: c++, json, mongodb, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a `bsoncxx::document::view bsonObj` that is a nested BSON document, it contains sub-documents and sub-arrays (an object that contains an array that then again contains a document, etc). When I access a document the returned object is of type `bsoncxx::document::element` and when I access an array the returned object is of type `bsoncxx::array::element`.

The problem is that I need this access to always return the same type. Is there some way to convert one type into the other?

[image]